# HMACSHA512Algorithm is obsolete. HMAC SHA based algorithms are not secure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, .net-6.0

I have an old website using JWT (https://jwt.io/) which im converting to .Net 6 Core.

I installed the latest version of JWT (10.0.3) via NuGet.

I migrate the existing code and get a warning on the below line

```
IJwtAlgorithm algo = new HMACSHA512Algorithm();
```

The warning is

*HMACSHA512Algorithm is obsolete. HMAC SHA based algorithms are not secure to protect modern web applications. Consider switching to RSASSA or ECDSA.*

Further down i have the code

```
var dec = new JwtDecoder(serialisor, vtor, urlEncode);
```

which wouldnt compile so changed it to

```
var dec = new JwtDecoder(serialisor, vtor, urlEncode, algo);
```

For the warning, generally Visual Studio gives some fixes to use but this time it didnt and im somewhat lost.

I searched around and all i could find was creating some certificate but i clearly dont have this within the code im porting from.

I tried to change the above line to the equivalent RSA i.e. XXXAlgorithm but it needed some value passed into the constructor.

What should i change `HMACSHA512Algorithm` to?

Comment: Are you trying to just decode the JWT, or there is also part of the application that does the JWT encoding?

Comment: Yes i have 2 keys saved. Further down the code i do see Decode and Encode methods but so far no errors on that just yet

Comment: https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt/pull/384#issuecomment-1325905125 It seems the creator of the JWT project might be mistaken (or at least misleading about it). See also https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/194830/recommended-asymmetric-algorithms-for-jwt/233863#233863 You do need to make sure your secret is long enough I think

Answer (score 1):

The warning about this algorithm being obsolete comes from JWT. It was added in this pull request: https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt/pull/384

At a later point in time they decided to revert this change. You can read their reasoning and the timeline of these changes in the pull request comments.

You have a few options:

- You can ignore the warning
- You can update to a later version of JWT
- You can replace your HMAC SHA algorithm with RSASSA or ECDSA

Pick the option that fits the security requirements of your application.